# iOS : Healthkit get Oxygen Saturation in real time

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, health-monitoring

I'm new to HealthKit framework and wants real time oxygen saturation in blood stream.

**REF :** https://github.com/coolioxlr/watchOS-2-heartrate

FROM THIS REPO i have tried to make query for oxygen saturation

```
   func createOxygenSaturationStreamingQuery(_ workoutStartDate: Date) -> HKQuery? {

        guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .oxygenSaturation) else { return nil }
        let datePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: workoutStartDate, end: nil, options: .strictEndDate )

        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[datePredicate])

        let oxygenSaturationQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType,
                                                       predicate: predicate,
                                                       anchor: nil,
                                                       limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, sampleObjects, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in

            self.updateOxygenSaturation(sampleObjects)
        }

        oxygenSaturationQuery.updateHandler = {(query, samples, deleteObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
            self.updateOxygenSaturation(samples)
        }
        return oxygenSaturationQuery
    }

    func updateOxygenSaturation(_ samples: [HKSample]?) {

        guard let oxygenSaturationSamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {return}

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // RETURN FROM HERE AS EMPTY ARRAY
            guard let sample = oxygenSaturationSamples.first else { return }
            let value = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "%/min"))
            let stringValue = String(UInt16(value))
            self.label.setText(stringValue)
            // retrieve source from sample
            let name = sample.sourceRevision.source.name
            print("sample.sourceRevision.source.name : \(name)")
            print("PERCENT : \(stringValue)")
        }
    }
```

**P.S : I'M CHECKING IN SIMULATOR**

I'm getting Heart Rate from that repo, but getting oxygen level empty?

Let me know what wrong i have done and how can i correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169843/discussion-between-abhishek-thapliyal-and-moaz-khan).

Comment: @Osman: At that moment watch is not capable of SPO2 i.e. Oxygen Saturation Data. You need to check latest Health Kit Updates. for same for above I Had to start indoor workout in order to get data.

Answer (score 0):

watchOS doesn't automatically record Oxygen Saturation samples, so you shouldn't expect to get any results back unless you have a device that is recording samples of this type and writing them to HealthKit using an app.

Comment: Install an app that records Oxygen Saturation.